# Дальнейшая регистрация в Firebase по телефону

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-database

Как продолжить регистрацию, если ранее этого пользователя не было в firebase?
Авторизация/регистрация проходит по телефону. Как понять что пользователя раньше не было в БД? В документации Firebase нет про мою проблему, информации.
Моя цель:
Проверить был этот пользователь ранее зарегистрирован:
Если да, то отправить его на главный layout, если его не было, то отправить его layout, чтобы он ввел имя и тд.

Как это осуществить? Я вдохновлялся Авторизацией/Регистрацией Telegram.

Код из LoginActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mCurrentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    mCountyCode = findViewById(R.id.country_code);
    mPhone = findViewById(R.id.phone);
    send_btn = findViewById(R.id.send_message_btn);
    send_progress_bar = findViewById(R.id.send_message_progress_bar);
    helpTextWorking = findViewById(R.id.helpTextWorking);

    send_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String county_code = mCountyCode.getText().toString();
            String phone_number = mPhone.getText().toString();

            String full_phone_number = "+" + county_code + "" + phone_number;

            if(county_code.isEmpty() || phone_number.isEmpty()){
                helpTextWorking.setText("Please Fill in the form to continue");
                helpTextWorking.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                send_progress_bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                send_btn.setEnabled(false);

                PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
                        full_phone_number,
                        60,
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                        LoginActivity.this,
                        mCallbacks
                );
            }
        }
    });

    mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            helpTextWorking.setText("Verifecation Failed, please try again.");
            helpTextWorking.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            send_progress_bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            send_btn.setEnabled(true);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(final String s, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken) {
            super.onCodeSent(s, forceResendingToken);

            new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
                    new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            Intent otpIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, OtpActivity.class);
                            otpIntent.putExtra("AuthCredentials", s);
                            startActivity(otpIntent);
                        }
                    },
                    10000);
        }
    };

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(mCurrentUser != null){
        sendUserToHome();
    }
}

private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        sendUserToHome();
                    } else {
                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            // The verification code entered was invalid
                            helpTextWorking.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            helpTextWorking.setText("There was an error verifying OTP");
                        }
                    }
                    send_progress_bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    send_btn.setEnabled(true);
                }
            });
}

private void sendUserToHome(){
    Intent homeIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(homeIntent);
    finish();
}
```

Если Google Play не нашёл смс подтверждения, которое послал на введенный телефон идёт пере адресация на OtpActivity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_otp);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mCurrentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    mVereficationID = getIntent().getStringExtra("AuthCredentials");

    errorHelpText = findViewById(R.id.helpTextErrorVerfecationCode);
    PR_verefication = findViewById(R.id.verefecationOTPCode);
    vereficationCode = findViewById(R.id.OTPcode);
    btnVerefication = findViewById(R.id.vereficationCode);

    btnVerefication.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String otp = vereficationCode.getText().toString();

            if(otp.isEmpty()){
                errorHelpText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                errorHelpText.setText("Please fill in the form and try again");
            } else {

                PR_verefication.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnVerefication.setEnabled(false);

                PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(mVereficationID, otp);
                signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);

            }

        }
    });
}

private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
        .addOnCompleteListener(OtpActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    sendUserToHome();
                } else {
                    if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                        // The verification code entered was invalid
                        errorHelpText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        errorHelpText.setText("There was an error verifying OTP");
                    }
                }
                PR_verefication.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                btnVerefication.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if(mCurrentUser != null){
        sendUserToHome();
    }
}

public void sendUserToHome(){
    Intent homeIntent = new Intent(OtpActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    homeIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(homeIntent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: вы бы хоть код какой-то добавили, а то так не очень понятно где именно у вас проблемы

Comment: Добавил весь код, который используется для авторизации/регистрации